# Delete Tuples in more dimensional list if same

Tags: python, tuples, double, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples namely:

```
[[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]], [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]], [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 's')]], [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 's')]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 'q')]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 'q')]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 's')]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 's')]], [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]], [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]], [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 's')]], [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 's')]], **[[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('t', 'q')]]**, [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('v', 'q')]], [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('t', 's')]], [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('v', 's')]]]
```

But now for example the element `[[('p','u'),('r','w')], [('t','q')]]`

is the same as `[[('r','w'),('p','u')], [('t','q')]]`, which are marked **fat** in the list.

So in the list I have 16 elements, where every element is double.

Now, I want to delete the duplicates, that I have only the first eight elements left.

So naively, I've tried with

```
[[list(y) for y in set([tuple(set(x)) for x in doublegammas1])]]
```

But here, he says:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So my question:

How can I extend the list comprehension, that it works for a more dimensional list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mutable object (such as a list or a set) cannot be a member of a set. You can use a frozenset, which is immutable.

```
main_list = [[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]],
             [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]],
             [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 's')]],
             [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 's')]],
             [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 'q')]],
             [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 'q')]],
             [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 's')]],
             [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 's')]],
             [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]],
             [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]],
             [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 's')]],
             [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 's')]],
             [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('t', 'q')]],
             [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('v', 'q')]],
             [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('t', 's')]],
             [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('v', 's')]]]

main_set = set(tuple(frozenset(innermost_list) for innermost_list in sublist) for sublist in main_list)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(main_set)
```

Output:

```
{(frozenset({('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')}), frozenset({('t', 'q')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('v', 'q')})),
 (frozenset({('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')}), frozenset({('v', 'q')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('t', 's')})),
 (frozenset({('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')}), frozenset({('t', 's')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('v', 's')})),
 (frozenset({('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')}), frozenset({('v', 's')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('t', 'q')}))}
```

To convert back to the original structure of nested lists:

```
new_list = [[list(frozen) for frozen in subtuple] for subtuple in main_set]
pprint(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]],
 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]],
 [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]],
 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 's')]],
 [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 's')]],
 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 's')]],
 [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 's')]],
 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]]]
```

**UPDATE:**

A solution that removes the duplicate items in-place from the input data.

```
unique = []

for item in main_list[:]:
    frozen_item = frozenset(frozenset(innermost_list) for innermost_list in item)
    if frozen_item not in unique:
        unique.append(frozen_item)
    else:
        main_list.remove(item)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) So how did you learn that stuff?
Is there some tutorial?

Comment: The advantage of this solution is it only uses 2 lines. The disadvantage is you are repeating logic (how the list is constructed) by the fact you unravel it via hashing, then put it back together again in `new_list`.

Comment: @jpp I added an in-place solution that seems to work (more as an exercise though, since the original question asked for comprehension rather than loop).

Comment: @7t7Studios, Why not use `set`? i.e. `unique = set()` and `unique.add(frozen_item)`. This, by the way, then becomes identical to `unique_everseen` in my solution.

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same, apart from having to import a 3rd party module. Btw do you know why they make an alias for `seen.add()`? Is it faster that way? Anyway, thanks for linking the libraries, there's lot of interesting stuff there.

Answer (score 2):

Lists aren't hashable, tuples *are* hashable. You then need to take a `set` of these tuples. But inside these tuples, you want to disregard order. But a *tuples of sets* are not hashable, so instead you need to use tuples of [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) objects:

```
uniques = {tuple(map(frozenset, i)) for i in doublegammas1}

print(uniques)

{(frozenset({('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')}), frozenset({('t', 'q')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')}), frozenset({('v', 'q')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')}), frozenset({('v', 's')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('t', 's')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('t', 'q')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('v', 'q')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')}), frozenset({('v', 's')})),
 (frozenset({('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')}), frozenset({('t', 's')}))}
```

You can then apply this via the [`itertools` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also available in 3rd party libraries as [`toolz.unique`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique) or [`more_itertools.unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen):

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

def uniquekey(x):
    return tuple(map(frozenset, x))

res = list(unique_everseen(doublegammas1, key=uniquekey))

print(res)

[[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]],
 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]],
 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 's')]],
 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 's')]],
 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 'q')]],
 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 'q')]],
 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 's')]],
 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 's')]]]
```

#### Input data

```
# input data
doublegammas1 = [[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]],
                 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]],
                 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('t', 's')]],
                 [[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [('v', 's')]],
                 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 'q')]],
                 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 'q')]],
                 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('t', 's')]],
                 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [('v', 's')]],
                 [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 'q')]],
                 [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 'q')]],
                 [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('t', 's')]],
                 [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [('v', 's')]],
                 [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('t', 'q')]],
                 [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('v', 'q')]],
                 [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('t', 's')]],
                 [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [('v', 's')]]]
```