# Delete duplicate tuples and lists in list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples and lists in python:

```
gammagammalambda = [[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]], [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]], [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]
```

Where

```
[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]
```

is the same as

```
[[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]
```

So now, I want to remove these double elements, in order to have

```
[[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]
```

For that, I want to use List comprehension and I've tried with

```
main_set = set(tuple(frozenset(innermost_list) for innermost_list in sublist) for sublist in gammagammalambda)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Hope, you can help me.

Comment: How did you even end up with such a nested list structure?

Comment: By using list.pop ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is the following:

```
gammagammalambda = [[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
                    [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
                    [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
                    [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]

d = {frozenset(e[0]) : e for e in reversed(gammagammalambda)}
result = list(d.values())

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]
```

Create a dictionary where the keys represent the values that must be unique, for each key set as value the entire element of `gammagammalambda`, finally the unique values are the values of the dictionary `d`.

Or a more *straightforward* alternative:

```
gammagammalambda = [[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
                    [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
                    [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
                    [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]


seen = set()
result = []
for e in gammagammalambda:
    key = frozenset(e[0])
    if key not in seen:
        result.append(e)
        seen.add(key)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]], [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]
```

Comment: Cool thank you very much. So where did you lern this stuff?

Comment: @Armani42 Most of that stuff I learned from the questions and answers here on stackoverflow. Also many PyCon talks and tutorials can be helpful.

Comment: It seems the assumption is the `['q', 's'], ['t' ,'v']` bits need *not* be the same to ensure uniqueness. I'm not sure if this is the case, it could be the input data is not representative.

Comment: The thing is, I get these object by using a self written class. If you want to, I can send you the piece of the code somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373141/9209546), `list` is not hashable, `tuple` and `frozenset` *are* hashable.

You can accordingly define a "uniqueness key", and use the [`itertools` `unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also available in 3rd party libraries as [`toolz.unique`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique) or [`more_itertools.unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen):

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

L = [[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
     [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
     [[('r', 'u'), ('p', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
     [[('r', 'w'), ('p', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]

def unique_everseen(x):
    return frozenset(x[0]), tuple(map(tuple, x[1][0]))

res = list(unique(L, key=unique_key))
```

```
[[[('p', 'u'), ('r', 'w')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]],
 [[('p', 'w'), ('r', 'u')], [[[], ['q', 's'], ['t', 'v'], []]]]]
```